# Use Pyspark inside the python project

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Python project and trying to use `pyspark` within. I build a Python class and call Pyspark class and methods. I declare a `SparkConf` and create a configuration which ise used by Spark, then create a SparkSession with this conf. My spark environment is a cluster and I can use is as a cluster deploy mode and master as yarn. But, when I try to get instance of spark session, it can be seen on Yarn applications page as submitted, however it can not submit my python methods as a spark job. It works if i submit this python as single script, it can be run as job by Yarn.

Here is the sample code:

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn')\
    .config(conf=conf)\
    .appName('myapp')\
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.SparkContext()

rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
count = rdd.count()
print(sc.master)
print(count)
```

It works great when I submit it with `./bin/spark-submit myapp.py` and I see it running on Yarn. It does not work how I expect when I run it `python myapp.py` and can see on Yarn as an application with no job or executer assigned.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I already set .env variables including with Hadoop conf dir, spark conf dir, etc. and conf files core-site and yarn-site xmls. Thus, I did not need to mention them.